# How to escape and unescape backslashes and ''' with regex?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I need to ***escape*** all `'''` and `backslashes` in a `string`. So if the user inputs `\`, it should get transformed to `\\` or if the user inputs `'''`, it should get transformed to `\'''`.

**Example input:**

```
This is a test \. ABCDE ''' DEFG
```

**Example output:**

```
This is a test \\. ABCDE \''' DEFG
```

I also need ***unescape*** `backslashes` and `'''`.

**Example input:**

```
asdf \\\\ and \'''
```

**Example output:**

```
asdf \\ and '''
```

I tried something like this, but it's not working....

```
 input = input.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\\'), '\\\\')
```

**Edit:**
After trying the suggested solution from the comments escaping works, but unescaping not.

```
  String unescape(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(r"\'''", r"'''").replaceAll(r"\\", r"\");
  }
```

**Test**

```
  test("Unescape", () {
      String test = r" \\ TESTTEST ";
      String expected = r" \ TESTTEST ";
      expect(stringUtils.unescape(test), expected);
    });
```

**Output**

```
Expected: ' \\ TESTTEST '
Actual: ' \\\\\\\\ TESTTEST '
Which: is different.
            Expected:  \\ TESTTEST  ...
              Actual:  \\\\\\\\ TES ...
                         ^
             Differ at offset 3
```

Comment: I don't know Dart, but in many languages the string replacement function returns a new string, it doesn't modify the original string, so you need to assign the result: `input = input.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: Why regex? `s.replaceAll(r"\", r"\\").replaceAll("'''", r"\'''")` and unescape with `s.replaceAll(r"\'''", r"'''").replaceAll(r"\\", r"\")`

Comment: Does that work/suffice?

Comment: Thank you :) Escaping works, unescaping not. I'll update my question

Comment: Actually, unescape works, `print(r" \\ TESTTEST ".replaceAll(r"\'''", r"'''").replaceAll(r"\\", r"\"))` prints ``\ TESTTEST ``, you just preprocess the data with some methods - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For escaping, you may use

```
print(r"This is a test \. ABCDE ''' DEFG".replaceAll(r"\", r"\\").replaceAll(r"'''", r"\'''"));
// => This is a test \\. ABCDE \''' DEFG
```

Here, you replace all backslashes with double backslashes with `.replaceAll(r"\", r"\\")` and then replace all `'''` substrings with `\'''` substrings.

For unescaping, you may use

```
print(r"This is a test \\. ABCDE \''' DEFG".replaceAll(r"\'''", r"'''").replaceAll(r"\\", r"\"));
// => This is a test \. ABCDE ''' DEFG
```

Here, you replace all `\'''` substrings with `'''` substrings first, then replace double backslashes with single ones.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. I shouldn't code when being tired...